# Executing SQL query from C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to execute SQL query from C# code, but it doesn't return any values, but when I write query directly to SQL it works fine.

```
static int TestGettingData()
{
        int rows;
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [UserName] FROM [aspnet_Users]", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        return rows;
}
```

And connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name ="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=myServer;
            Database=MyDatabase;User 
            Id=User;
            Password=password;
            MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And `TestGettingData()` always returning -1.

Comment: "I'm trying to execute SQL query" - and yet you're calling `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get Data out of your Database

**ExecuteScalar**

if you have one result field you can use

```
string Command = "SELECT [UserName] FROM [aspnet_Users];";
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    myConnection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(Command, myConnection))
    {
        string Result = (string)myCommand.ExecuteScalar(); // returns the first column of the first row
    }
}
```

**SqlDataAdapter**

if you expect multiple rows / columns you can load it into a DataTable by

```
string Command = "SELECT [UserName] FROM [aspnet_Users]";
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Command, myConnection))
    {
        DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(dtResult);
    }
}
```

**SqlDataReader**

Another solution is the SQLDataReader. E.g. if you want to load all rows of a column into a List. This has less overhead than the DataAdapter.

```
List<string> Result = new List<string>();
string Command = "SELECT [UserName] FROM [aspnet_Users];";
using (SqlConnection mConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    mConnection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Command, mConnection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Result.Add((string)reader[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is ` myConnection.Open();` not required on the second example?

Comment: @BeKindToNewUsers _The Fill method implicitly opens the Connection that the DataAdapter is using if it finds that the connection is not already open_ - [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/bh8kx08z(v=vs.71)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 2):

Because [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) say so;

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. **For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1**. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

You can use `COUNT(*)` wiht [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get your number.

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT([UserName]) FROM [aspnet_Users]", connection))
{
     connection.Open();
     rows = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think is the best way to access and retrieve data from a DB:

**Create a DBconnection class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SQLexample
{
/// <summary>
/// A class that makes the connection to the SQL Database
/// </summary>
class DBconnection
{
    // variables
    private string sql_string;
    private string strCon;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da_1;

    // set methods
    public string Sql
    {
        set { sql_string = value; }
    }

    public string connection_string
    {
        set { strCon = value; }
    }

    // DataSet
    public System.Data.DataSet GetConnection
    {
        get { return MyDataSet(); }
    }

    // MyDataSet method
    private System.Data.DataSet MyDataSet()
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strCon);
        con.Open();

        da_1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, con);

        System.Data.DataSet dat_set = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da_1.Fill(dat_set, "Table_Data_1");

        con.Close();

        return dat_set;
    }

    // Update DB method
    public void UpdateDB(System.Data.DataSet ds)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da_1);
        cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
}
}
```

**Then, from your other classes, whenever you want to access DB you do it like this:**

```
try
{
    objConnect = new DBconnection();
    conStringAUTH = Properties.Settings.Default.authConnectionString;

    objConnect.connection_string = conStringAUTH;
    objConnect.Sql = "QUERY GOES HERE";

    ds = objConnect.GetConnection;

    // Data manipulation
    maxRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

    if (maxRows == 0)
    {
        // Your query returned no values
    }

}
catch (Exception err)
{
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
}
```

Hope this helps...