# TextBox completion when data entered in another TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, ms-access

Let's assume that I've two `TextBox` on my Form

[image: like this].

As you can see I have to enter a primary key on the first, and I want the 2nd `TextBox` to display the value of the field corresponding to this key.

I'm working with Access 2016 and we can considerate my table like this :

```
+----------+--------+------+---------+
| Field    | Type   | Null | Key     |
+----------+--------+------+---------+
| Item     | Number |  NO  | PRIMARY |
| Provider | Text   |  YES |         |
+----------+--------+------+---------+
```

***Here is my question*** : is it possible to display the Provider field with the `DataBindings` properties ? Otherwise how would you achieve this ?
(**C#**)

Comment: A simple `select` query and `datareader` to populate the textbox is one way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As P. Pat already mentioned u can use a simple SELECT query. Something like this:

```
cn.Open(); //open connection
string comm = "SELECT Provider From table WHERE Item = @Item";
cmd = new SqlCeCommand(comm, cn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Item", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = textbox1.Text;

textbox2.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //get first row with the right item
cn.Close(); //close connection
```

now your privider is in textbox 2.

You can also look it up right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392251/executing-sql-query-from-c-sharp-code).

Please note: The example above is only out of my memory. Not tested.

Comment: Yeah, you are both right. But want I wanted to achieve is not to query the base.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue !

```
private void textBoxItem_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int item;
    var row;

    if (int.TryParse(textBoxItem.Text, out item))
    {
        row = dataSet.PROVIDERS.FindByitem(item);

        if (row != null)
            textBoxProvider.Text = row.provider;
    }
}
```